# Refer to coordinates of bounding box of symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikz, I am doing multiple times essentially the same drawing but with different writings at the nodes. Thus, I would like to refer to the coordinates of the bounding box of the writings at the nodes to build my picture, so that all these drawings look "the same."

Minimal example for what I would like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\node[left] (x) at (0, 0) {[text A]};
\node[right] (y) at (2, 0) {[text B]};
    
\draw[->] ($([right side of text A], 0) + (0.1, 0.1)$) -- ($([left side of text B], 0) + (-0.1, 0.1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There are some questions about coordinates of bounding boxes in this site already, but I was not able to find something that I was able to apply to my problem.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, can you complete your MWE to compile it directly adding a screenshot of the problem (eventually)?

Comment: It's not clear to me how "right side of text A" differs from `x.east`.

Comment: @adl Probably because `x.east` might be what I want. How do you use it? It seems to give me errors...

Comment: @adl Ah I was missing the `positioning` tikzlibrary. You can post this as an answer if you want. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud  please have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[left] (x) at (0, 0) {text A};
\node[right] (y) at (2, 0) {text B};
\draw[->] ($(x.east) + (0.1, 0.1)$) -- ($(y.west) + (-0.1, 0.1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is

```
\node[right=2cm of x] (y)  {text B};
```

Also, your arrow is not aligned correctly at center of the nodes `x` and `y`  you need to use the correct syntax as below

```
\draw[->, >=stealth] (x) to (y);
```

where `>=stealth` is the type of arrow

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (x) at (0, 0) {text A};
\node[right=2cm of x] (y)  {text B};
\draw[->, >=stealth] (x) to (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other possible ways: `([shift={(-0.1,0.1)}] y.west)` and `([xshift=-0.1cm, yshift=0.1cm] y.west)`. Note that in the latter style, the default unit is `pt`, therefore `([xshift=-0.1, yshift=0.1] y.west)` is *not* equivalent to `([shift={(-0.1,0.1)}] y.west)` unless you chose very particular `x` and `y` vectors (when using `([shift={(-0.1,0.1)}] y.west)`, `-0.1` is multiplied by the `x` vector of the `xyz` coordinate system, and `0.1` is multiplied by the `y` vector of said coordinate system; these vectors can be modified with `x=...` and `y=...` options usually passed in the optional argument of the `tikzpicture` environment).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[left] (x) at (0, 0) {text A};
\node[right] (y) at (2, 0) {text B};
\draw[->] ([shift={(0.1,0.1)}] x.east) --
          ([xshift=-0.1cm, yshift=0.1cm] y.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another great possibility, thanks!